# How to join the same table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

The scenerio of query is

```
select * from table1 where colName = 'John' and age(select age from
 table1) <> 21
```

Need data with all the row names as John but their age should not be 21.

How to join the same table?

Comment: Why do you need to a `join`? (or `subquery` )

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
select * from table1 where names = 'John' and age <> 21
```

You can check this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/and_or.php) to understand how we can join multiple conditions with `select` query in `ORACLE`.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggest, you don't need a self-join for this scenario. However, self joins are possible in `SQL`

```
SELECT * from table1 t1,table1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.name='John' and t2.age <> 21
```

But you really shouldn't do this for your scenario.

Comment: When you know that he shouldn't use this, then why are you suggesting? Is that good from performance point of view? We should avoid joins if we can. :)

Comment: I'm suggesting only because the OP wants this!

Comment: We should suggest solution what is best, not what OP wants.. Because this solution is not for this user, but for those users as well who will see this answer in future.

Comment: People who will see this answer in future most likely reach the question with a search query of "How to join the same table in sql". First, we have to answer their question and then warn them to use it properly.